# get data from server using axios with react

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am new using react and I'd like to get data from server, so I tried:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { movies: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then(response => this.setState({ movies: response.data.data }))
  }

  renderUsers() {
    const { movies } = this.state

    return movies.map( user => (
      <div key={id}>{title} {releaseYear}</div>
    ))
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{ this.renderUsers() }</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

and my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="movies.js" type = "text/babel"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

the problem is, I get nothing in my page. any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Did you package this with webpack/babel or are you trying to run it as shown? If the latter then I believe you need to include babel otherwise your JSX won't be valid. Include: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>` in your head section. If that's not it, then use the developer console of your browser and share any error messages you see.

Comment: Seems the response data will be `response.data.movies` instead of `response.data.data`. Another problem I see is, in `renderUsers` it should be `<div key={user.id}>{user.title} {user.releaseYear}</div>`. You might wanna use `movie` instead of `user` too.

Answer (score 2):

Few issues which I have fixed

- setState in componentDidMount is picking wrong key. You need to set response.data.movies instead of response.data.data
- the map function is used incorrectly in renderUsers function. You need to pick id, title and releaseYear from the correct variable instead of directly using them

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { movies: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then(response => this.setState({ movies: response.data.movies }))
  }

  renderUsers() {
    const { movies } = this.state

    return movies.map( data => (
      <div key={data.id}>{data.title} {data.releaseYear}</div>
    ))
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{ this.renderUsers() }</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="movies.js" type = "text/babel"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much! In localhost it doesn't work, but I think it might be some browser protection. any ideas how to make it work in localhost?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console? The way you have included the movies.js component using script tag is incorrect. You need to follow what @jarmod has commented and then post any errors which you are getting

Comment: oh, sorry, it worked. babel.min.js was not in head section... thanks!